# python script shuffle file with lines

Tags: python

I have this script for years, I use it to scramble words in a text file.
But I have a file line by line, and the script is shuffling but it deletes the line break
he's leaving everything on the same line, do you have any solution for this?
I tried 'sort -r' but it just does the reverse, it doesn't shuffle.

```
import random

file = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
text = file.read()
file.close()

text = text.split()
random.shuffle(text)
text = ' '.join(text)

print(text)
```

Comment: Hint: what does `text = ' '.join(text)` do? Could you replace `' '` with something else? Or maybe print your text a different way, without using `str.join()` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly this should solve your issue:

```
import random

final_text = ""

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace("\n", "")
    random.shuffle(lines)
    final_text = "\n".join(lines)

print(final_text)
```

Comment: Teddy Thank you for your attention, but it did not scramble.

Comment: It does scramble the words. Should it scramble the letters?

Comment: Should the lines be scrambled and still have the same words in it or should the words also shuffled?

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer above, with an example

Comment: Ok, i have edited my answer i hope this time i understood the question correctly.

Comment: Congratulations Teddy! Solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `read().splitlines()` to add all lines as element in list without trailing newline and print unpacked list using starred expression with `\n` as separator:

```
from random import shuffle

with open('myfile.txt') as file: text = file.read().splitlines(); shuffle(text)

print(*text, sep='\n')
```